# How to find the number of lines needed for a text to wrap in a fixed width in java

Tags: java

Hi Iam wrapping my text inside a column using white-space:pre-wrap property in CSS.After the text wrapped I want to find exact number of lines it have taken to wrap completely.The text might be numeric,alphabetic,alphanumeric,japanese,special characters.

In my condition for a font size of 12 px and width approximately 11.5 em while giving japanese characters alone 11 charactes fits in first line then the next 11 characters wrapped to next line.And while giving English characters alone 24 characters fits in a line and next 24 characters to newline.But number of characters per line differs even for English lowercase letters and Uppercase letters.Only 20 English uppercase letters fits single line and next 20 characters in newline.
Based on number of characters per line for a particular type of text I used wordUtils.wrap method.

For English wordUtils.wrap(text,24,null,true)
For Japanese wordUtils.wrap(text,11,null,true)
It works fine for japanese alone English alone String
But not for the string with japanese English mixed and string with only numeric characters.

I also tried FontRenderContext to calculate width of each character and wrap based on  fixed width 138px(ie 11.5*12). But font rendering differs browser to browser.

Is there anyother way in java or Js?
Kindly help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Speaking of wrapping text, here are some [basic markdown tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: If you want consistency with font-size use monospaced fonts like Consolas, Monaco, monospace, etc. Use font relative units `ex` and `ch`.

Comment: Whether the basic markdown tips useful for wrapping in java code?